# python web-socket client where is this logging from?

Tags: python, sockets, logging, websocket, request

I'm using python web-socket client library to pull websocket stream (https://github.com/liris/websocket-client and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client). I'm trying to format the logging by getLogger("class name or package name") then setFormatter and setLevel. but I can't catch where is this logging from? (which class or which package)

```
--- request header ---
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: ws-feed.abc.com:443
Origin: http://ws-feed.abc.com:443
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 5vpSzJJvew3SGjn0Xu/Ok93g==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13


-----------------------
--- response header ---
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Fri, 04 Sep 2015 03:12:20 GMT
Connection: upgrade
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d5e4215a3e383c4d29ca4d5c8a14bf3221441336339; expires=Sat, 03-Sep-16 03:12:19 GMT; path=/; domain=.abc.com; HttpOnly
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: WirZtRsde5jtW79ArrW02oiSI=
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
CF-RAY: 2206831e3421edd-SJC
-----------------------
```

I tried getLogger('websocket'), which is the name of module I import, but doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

`websocket.enableTrace(True)`
change "True" to "False" to disable the logger.

Answer (score 0):

It will be solved by specifying stdout for logging. Try to add the following lines at the top of your code:

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
```